# Joining two tables with Pandas, on a columns where there are repeated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Looking to join two tables together (tables 1 and 2) to look like table 3. I tried using pandas join on the dataframes, but I keep getting errors for trying to join on columns with repeated values.

Ex:

Table 1

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B1 |
| 2 | A1 | B1 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 |

Table 2

| ID | Property |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Property 1 |
| 1 | Property 2 |
| 2 | Property 1 |
| 2 | Property 2 |
| 2 | Property 3 |

Table 3 (expected output)

| ID | A | B | Property |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B1 | Property 1 |
| 1 | A1 | B1 | Property 2 |
| 2 | A1 | B1 | Property 1 |
| 2 | A1 | B1 | Property 2 |
| 2 | A1 | B1 | Property 3 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | Property 1 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | Property 2 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | Property 3 |
| 2 | A3 | B3 | Property 1 |
| 2 | A3 | B3 | Property 2 |
| 2 | A3 | B3 | Property 3 |

Comment: You need to merge the dfs , what did you do? what error you got , you need to provide more info

Answer (score 0):

To merge them you can use `merge` method:

```
out = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID')
```

output:

```
>>>
   ID   A   B    Property
0   1  A1  B1  Property 1
1   1  A1  B1  Property 2
2   2  A1  B1  Property 1
3   2  A1  B1  Property 2
4   2  A1  B1  Property 3
5   2  A2  B2  Property 1
6   2  A2  B2  Property 2
7   2  A2  B2  Property 3
```